# Hide mail icon from top bar

Tags: 11.04, mail, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove that envelope icon from the menu bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70518/how-do-i-remove-that-envelope-icon-from-the-menu-bar)

I don't have a use for the mail icon because this machine does not touch the internet. How can I hide that icon?