# How do I remove that envelope icon from the menu bar?

Tags: messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the Mail icon indicator applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65858/how-to-remove-the-mail-icon-indicator-applet)

Is there a way to remove that envelope icon from the menu bar?  It's around the top right corner.  It contains Chat, Evolution, Broadcast, Pidgin, ...