# Ubuntu 12.04 remove email icon

Tags: gnome

I use GNOME Classic desktop environment on my netbook. How can I remove the email icon (or the whole Messenger)? Although I can delete all the icons from the panel, I only want to delete just this one icon.

Comment: Can you translate this please.  Ask Ubuntu is an English only site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [How do I remove that envelope icon from the menu bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70518/how-do-i-remove-that-envelope-icon-from-the-menu-bar) and others. And I'm only answering this one, because I stumbled upon this one. Since this question isn't answered try out this link: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/05/how-to-remove-messaging-menu-indicator-in-ubuntu-unity/.

And if that is not understandable, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```